# WPF C# MS SQL - DesktopVersion and Save/Load data to file

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, desktop-application

I have an application that currently runs in MS SQL Server Standard in multiple clients/local server. The program was builded using WPF + StoredProcedures/functions/triggers, and there aren't MS Jobs.

I want to create an desktop version of my application, where the user can save all the data to a file and load it in another desktop with the program running.

I never done this type of application before, and I have a few doubts about how I should do this,  I don't know if what I'm planning is going to work.

Basically, I was thinking in install my application with SQL Server Express and to save/restore it to files, I thought about calling backup/restore database through storedprocedures.

Am I thinking right? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to migrate settings from MS SQL to file?

Comment: I want to store all the data that is in the database to a file. Not the settings, but the data that is stored in the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand why you would need to export the entire contents of the database to a file.  The central database should be accessible by all of the client applications, avoiding the need for the client application to have its own dedicated copy of the database.  But ... if this is really what you want, then I think your two options are:

1.) Use Backup+Restore.

2.) Use LocalDB with the AttachDbFileName property, which is designed to keep your database in a single self-contained local file that you can read/write without having to connect to an actual database server.  Some starting info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I should have explained more about. I'm creating a new version of my program. I have the Client/Server version for bigger companies, but I want to have a single user desktop version for the small companies and also to offer a trial experience that don't need server installation.

Comment: Okay, then LocalDB is probably the best solution for you.

Comment: I'm going to try it out tonight! Thank you!